# jstree create edit rename functions with contextmenu plugin and laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, jstree

I am using jstree and contextmenu plugin to create a folder tree with laravel, front end everything works but i dont know how to connect the JavaScript functions to laravel controller  functions so i can create , rename and delete a node and save it to mysql database

I have the javascript functions with console.log message ready

```
     <script>
    $(function() {
    $('#container').jstree({
    "core" : {
      "check_callback" : true,
      "themes" : { "stripes" : true },
     },
    "plugins" : ['crrm','dnd','search','contextmenu'],

    }).on('rename_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
        console.log('rename');

    }).on('delete_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
        console.log('deleted');

    }).on('create_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
        console.log('create');
    });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The data object in the callback has the new node created & its parent. You could use that to send a ajax call to your laravel code. You will have to implement some sort of REST services with the laravel controller functions. The question here looks too broad, could you elaborate with some specifics.

Comment: Hello @StephenS , i dont know what else to explain!? i have a laravel project  and i use the jstree with the contextmenu plugin. I  want when i create rename or delete a node to be saved  in a mysql  database. what looks "too broad" ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use ajax to connect to the controller.

Add this into your three .on statements

```
function(e, data) {
$.ajax({
  url: '/controllerMethod',
  method: 'post',
  data: data,
  success:function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: hello, if i add this to delete statement for example i get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined. Any idea?

Comment: When you debug what line does it fail on?

Comment: The problem i think is at “data:data “ but i will give you more information at Monday morning as i don’t have access on weekends , thanks for your help !

Comment: hello @Ducker here is the error,
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined
    at bind (jstree.min.js:2)
    at bind (jstree.min.js:4)
    at bind (jstree.min.js:5)
    at bind (jstree.min.js:4)
    at i (app.js:1)
    at Ot (app.js:1)
    at Ot (app.js:1)
    at Function.E.param (app.js:1)
    at Function.ajax (app.js:1)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (5:237)

Comment: The error you're now getting most likely relates to what you're passing in as data. Ensure that what you're passing over matches what your endpoint is expecting. Or just create a simple endpoint that takes no parameters and pass no data for now to ensure your syntax is correct, then build up from there

Comment: If you know how to do crud  with latavel please give me an example , i need every new node that i create under nested li to be saved under the parent id.. please im stuck!

Comment: You'll need to read up on ajax and laravel first. [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_ajax.htm) is a link that will begin to help you. What you need to do is modify your controllers and route.php file to set up for using AJAX. Once you've done that then you can start to pass data from the nodes into your controllers